# Consumer key and secret not working

Tags: rest

1. I am using the following tool:  Advanced Rest Client, installed from google extensions to make a simple test - request to our sf instance.
2. I have created a connected app in our sf instance, and produced the consumer key and secret.
3. My test request is as follows:

https://cs14.my.salesforce.com/%22,oauth_consumer_key=%22***************%22,oauth_nonce=%22LUIE4X2Q0QO2JJSQ%22,oauth_signature_method=%22PLAINTEXT%22,oauth_timestamp=%221413287122%22,oauth_version=%221.0%22,oauth_signature=%22********%22

where everything else in the request apart from consumer key and secret are generated automatically.

I am getting an 'expired or invalid session id', no matter what differentiations I try in the above requests. Any ideas why ?

Comment: Why are you using oauth 1.0 if you can use outh 2.0?

Comment: I am not sure how you can manipulate it to work 2.0 ?